# Differentiate function with one variable occurring in several places

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

> **Problem** Suppose $\varphi(x)$ is defined by a formula in which $x$ occurs in several places. (e.g. $\varphi(x) = \dfrac{x^2e^x}{x+3}$.)
>
> 1) Show that the function's derivative is obtained by differentiating with respect to each of the x's in turn, treating the others as constants, and adding the results.
>
> 2) Notice the rules for differentiating sums and products are special cases of this result, obtained by taking $\varphi(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ or $\varphi(x) = f(x)g(x)$. What is the derivative of $\varphi(x) = f(x)^{g(x)}$?

The hint says

> If the variable occurs in $n$ places in the formula for $\varphi$, let $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be the function of n variables obtained by replacing each of the $x$'s in the formula by a different variable.

My thought for (1) is to take the partial derivative of $\varphi(x)$ with respect to each $x_j$ using chain rule, but I am not sure how to write down the expression. I have no clue how to approach (2). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Removed pde tag as this is not related to partial-differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second function $\psi(x)=(x, ..., x)$ with $n$ copies of $x$. Now for example if $\varphi(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$, we have $F(x_1, x_2)=f(x_1)^{g(x_2)}$ and $\varphi(x)=F(\psi(x))$. Now you can apply the chain rule and compute the derivative of $\varphi$.